# Converting from time interval to a statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change time values in my database into statement. For example, the time interval between 06:00:00 to 12:00:00 as morning, 12:00:00 to 17:00:00 as afternoon and so forth. I was using such method:

```
Update dbo.denouncement_term_day_time

Set time_den = 'Morning'

WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR, time_den) >= 6
  AND DATEPART(MINUTE, time_den) >= 00
  AND DATEPART(SECOND, time_den) >= 00) AND
  (DATEPART(HOUR, time_den) <= 11
  AND DATEPART(MINUTE, time_den) <= 59
  AND DATEPART(SECOND, time_den) <= 59)
```

But now, it is not working and it gives me the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." even though the time is varchar. As I said it works for the same data if it is for first 50-100 rows. But for 250,000 raw it gives this error.

Thank you,

Comment: Please add a tag based on what flavor of sql you are using (mysql for example). You can do that with the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: what is point to do `AND DATEPART(MINUTE, time_den) >= 00` `AND DATEPART(MINUTE, time_den) <= 59` and etc... You can compare just Hour `WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR, time_den) >= 6 AND (DATEPART(HOUR, time_den) <= 11`

Answer (score 1):

I hardly know where to start on this one...

1. Why are you trying to call DATEPART multiple times, on a varchar() field? This requires implicit conversion to a datetime type first, which is going to be expensive. It would be much better to convert the strings into a datetime and work from there.
2. Don't store 'Morning', etc. in your database. Use CASE to export the friendly value based on the datetime value. You can do this directly in your SELECT, or abstract it away in a VIEW.
3. Calling DATEPART() on this field also means you're guaranteed to get errors in the future, since you're setting strings like 'Morning' back in the place of the date/time strings.
4. DATEPART(MINUTE, x) >= 0 and DATEPART(SECOND, x) >=0 will ALWAYS return true. There is no such thing as a negative minute or second.
5. Likewise, the last comparison of 11:59:59 can be simplified as DATEPART(HOUR, d) < 12. Boom. No need to look at minutes or seconds. (This also handles fractional seconds, which you likely aren't dealing with in string form.

The core issue is that something in your varchar() field isn't a date/time that can be converted back implicitly.

My solution, using a computed column:

```
  -- Add a new column for the proper datetime values.
  ALTER TABLE denouncement_term_day_time ADD datetime_den datetime;
  -- Clean your data before running the next line.
  UPDATE denouncement_term_day_time SET datetime_den = CAST(time_den AS datetime);
  -- Once converted, don't store the string dates anymore, it's wasteful
  ALTER TABLE denouncement_term_day_time DROP COLUMN time_den;
  -- Add a computed column to return the friendly time.
  ALTER TABLE denouncement_term_day_time ADD friendly_time AS
        CASE
          WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, datetime_den) > 16 THEN 'Evening'
          WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, datetime_den) > 11 THEN 'Afternoon'
          ELSE 'Morning'
        END
```

Even this, however, has problems, as it assumes the user is in the same time zone as the data. Ideally, this sort of thing should be done in the UI layer, where you have access to the user's location, language, etc., not deep inside your data layer.

Comment: yes you are right, this is not a good way to do it. but I am a total beginner and I need to do this for my project to analyse data in ms sql data tools. so, I will not use it again. thank you very much for your solution and comments. When I tried this solution, I got 'Invalid column name 'datetime_den'.' error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.denouncement_term_day_time
    ADD time_den_new VARCHAR(20) NULL
GO

UPDATE dbo.denouncement_term_day_time
SET time_den_new = 
        CASE WHEN time_den BETWEEN '6:00:00' AND '11:59:59' THEN 'Morning'
             WHEN time_den BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '16:59:59' THEN 'Afternoon'
        END
WHERE time_den BETWEEN '6:00:00' AND '16:59:59'
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.denouncement_term_day_time DROP COLUMN time_den
GO

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.denouncement_term_day_time.time_den_new', 'time_den', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
Update dbo.denouncement_term_day_time
   Set time_den = 'Morning'
WHERE (DATEPART(HOUR,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 6
AND DATEPART(MINUTE,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 00
AND DATEPART(SECOND,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 00) 
AND ( DATEPART(HOUR,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 11
AND DATEPART(MINUTE,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 59
AND DATEPART(SECOND,  Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 59)
```

Comment: Thanks but this one gives "The datepart function requires 2 argument(s)." error.

Comment: Sorry but u can try this one
     Update dbo.denouncement_term_day_time
     Set [time_den] = 'Morning'

WHERE (
  DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 6
  AND DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 00
  AND DATEPART(SECOND, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) >= 00) AND
  (DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 11
  AND DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 59
  AND DATEPART(SECOND, CONVERT(Char(8), Convert(DATETIME, [time_den]), 8)) <= 59)